# SDL_Mixer set sound position

Tags: c, audio, skip, sdl-mixer

I was wondering if there is a functionality in the `SDL_Mixer` lib to skip to a certain position in a wav file. I've found out the there is a function called `Mix_SetMusicPosition` but it won't work with `.wav` files and it won't let you choose a channel. 
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
I figured out how to do it. Instead of calling an additional function I just changed the start pointer of the `abuf` variable located in `Mix_Chunk` structure. I calculated how many bytes are in a second in a 16 bit `.wav` file playing at 44khz and changed the starting pointer of `abuf` with that number times how many seconds I want to skip. And then changed the length of `alen`, also a variable located in the `Mix_Chunk` struct, with the same number of bytes.

Comment: If you change your edit into an answer with a small code example, it'd be more helpful for the site.

Answer (score 1):

I just read the docs for SDL Music and apparently Mix_SetMusicPosition only supports OGG, MP3 and MOD files.

Link: http://jcatki.no-ip.org:8080/SDL_mixer/SDL_mixer_65.html#SEC65

Obvious solution; convert your wav. files to your favorite previously mentioned file format.

Comment: Yeah I found that function too, but since I'm working with channels and `Mix_SetMusicPosition` doesn't support that I was wondering if there was another function somewhere hidden. Thanks for the effort though!